# Accessing spark cluster mode in spark submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run my spark scala code using spark submit. I want to access the spark cluster for this purpose. So, what should I use for the master in the Spark Context? I have used like this

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("spark://prod5:7077")
      .appName("MyApp")
      .getOrCreate;
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What should I use as the master for using spark cluster?

Comment: What exactly are the symptoms of _doesn't seem to work_? Please [edit] the question and include enough details for others to diagnose the problem (how do you call this code, was there a previous session, do you get any errors, and so on).

Comment: configuration seems to be ok. check your spark cluster 'prod5' is reachable/accessible.

Comment: @user6910411 - This is not the total code. I am trying to connect spark with cassandra. But when I use master("local[*]"), the code used the local spark and works until it gives the error of "GC overhead limit exceeded". I guess the memory of that server is not sufficient to carry out the task. So I was wondering if I could access the spark cluster for the task. My spark master in zeppelin says "spark://prod5:7077" so I used it. But after using it the screen just hangs up and no tasks are shown running. There is no error so I am not able to tell what went wrong.

Comment: @Kris - How can I check that?

Comment: @Anand Nautiyal: Ping the master node or IP.

Comment: @Kris - Please let me know the process. I will do it at my end.

Comment: ping prod5 or ping <IP>

Comment: @Kris - Okay. You meant I should ping the IP. Well, yes it is up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to submit your job in IDE,just make sure that "prod5" is the master, and try to change the port to 6066 by default.

Answer (score 0):

From official documentation -

```
spark-submit --class <main-class>  --master <master-url> --deploy-mode <deploy-mode>  --conf <key>=<value> ... # other options <application-jar>  [application-arguments]
```

Comment: I'd recommend linking the documentation whenever you reference it in a question/answer.